# RabbitMQ API - Get memory ussage

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ  for various tasks,

However  I  have a monitor service, which checks many things,  and I would  like  to  check the memory ussage of all nodes with RabbitMQ's API

I have tried all these (possibly not in the correct manner) : http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html

So,  My question is : Is it possible to retrieve the memory stats?  If so,  how?

Comment: Which version of rabbitmq are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTTP Api exposed by rabbitmq_management plugin.

Data about each node is accessible via `http://rmq_node:15672/api/nodes`. That will give you JSON array with object for each node which contains field mem_used.

Comment: Forgive  me, It's  friday... I  completely overlooked that field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by default the API will only include used memory, but no detailed breakdown of overall memory usage. I just learned the hard way that you need to pass an additional query parameter `memory=true` to get the detailed report.